# matplotlib value colorbar for scatter colors LogNorm

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I do understand that the '''matplotlib.colors.lognorm'''  will represent my value between [[0:1]](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/colormap_normalizations.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-colormap-normalizations-py).

How could I have the value next to the graduation?

In other case : Is there any possibility to display rather than the value evolution from [0:1] with my Vmin and my Vmax evolution following the same graduation.

exemple data

```
Date,T_mesure_Tmax,T_simu,Numero apt,V_mesure
13/01/2019 09:00:00,20,20,1,1
13/01/2019 09:10:00,66,66,14,1
13/01/2019 09:20:00,55.4,55.1925597696888,1,44
```

my code:

```
import os
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors 

filename ="essai2.txt"

dc = pd.read_csv(adr+filename)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(dc['T_mesure_Tmax'], dc['T_simu'],c=dc['V_mesure'],norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=dc['V_mesure'].min(), vmax=dc['V_mesure'].max()),
                   cmap='PuBu_r', s=10 )
plt.colorbar(sc,label="DHW volum [L]")
```

Visual with the trial (above)
[image: Visual with the trial]
Visual with the REAL trial (below)
[image: Visual with the real data]

matplotlib==3.7.3